# Files Uploading to Folder on Server but no Sql Injection on update in the Database Table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

The code i have used is uploading to the desired folder on the server correctly, but is not updating the columns in the Table at all? I don't want to use INSERT INTO as i,m trying to inject into a particular ROW. the row being the username selected on upload with the file. Can anybody help?

Here is the HTML form code -

```
      <form name= "admin_upload" class="sign-in-htm" id="upload" 
      action="/php/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form- 
      data">
      <div class="group">
      <label for="user" class="label">Enter Company or Employer Name: 
      </label>
      <input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="input">
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="group">
      <label for="attachment" class="label">Upload Test Result PDF: 
      </label>
      <input id="attachment" multiple name="files[]" 
      accept=".doc,.docx,.pdf" type="file" class="input">
      </div>
      <br>

      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-submit" name="submit" 
      value="submit" input type="submit">Submit Results</button>
  </form>
```

Here is the PHP code -

```
      if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
      {
      $statusMsg = $errorMsg = $updateValuesSQL = $errorUpload = 
      $errorUploadType = '';
      if(!empty(array_filter($_FILES['files']['name']))){
      foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $key=>$val){
        // File upload path
        $fileName = basename($_FILES['files']['name'][$key]);
        $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;

        // Check whether file type is valid
        $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
            // Upload file to server
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key], 
      $targetFilePath)){
                // Image db insert sql
                $updateValuesSQL .= "('".$fileName."'),";
            }else{
                $errorUpload .= $_FILES['files']['name'][$key].', ';
            }
        }else{
            $errorUploadType .= $_FILES['files']['name'][$key].', ';
        }
      }
      echo $_POST['username'];      
      if(isset($_POST['username'])){
      $username = $_POST['username'];
      }


      if(!empty($updateValuesSQL)){
        $updateValuesSQL = trim($updateValuesSQL,',');
        // Insert image file name into database
       $update = $link->$sql =("UPDATE users SET file_name = 
      '$updateValuesSQL' WHERE username = '$username'");
```

I am not getting any error messages and i have it set to return to the page if successful which is happening. Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Comment: The PHP code is invalid - there are more open curly braces( 9 ) than closing ( 6 )

Comment: Code is not showing any errors? and file is uploading to server no problem. Just the update in the database table. Also there is still some PHP code below that for the if success and if fail functions. So its not the amount of braces.

Comment: Well you ought to post correct code so as not to mislead. The above `$update = $link->$sql =` is confusing ~ it does not appear to do anything and even if it does/did - it is vulnerable to sql injection. Are you using `mysqli`?

Comment: Yes using mysqli, thats the bit of the code where i think i,m going wrong?

Comment: Tried to upload all the Code but it wouldn't let me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a little play around as the above was vulnerable and, IMO, a little hard to read. I hope the following will help - it does work OK

```
<?php

    /* assumed that you will replace this with your connection */
    require 'db.php';

?>
<?php

    $output=[]; //  log all actions & results to display to user if required


    if( isset( $_POST['submit'], $_POST['username'] ) && !empty( $_FILES['files'] ) ){

        function uploaderror( $error ){ 
            switch( $error ) { 
                case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: return "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini"; 
                case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE: return "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form"; 
                case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL: return "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded"; 
                case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE: return "No file was uploaded"; 
                case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR: return "Missing a temporary folder"; 
                case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE: return "Failed to write file to disk"; 
                case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION: return "File upload stopped by extension"; 
                default: return "Unknown upload error";
            }
        }

        /*************************************/
        /*       EDIT AS APPROPRIATE         */
        /*************************************/

        $targetDir='c:/temp/fileuploads/stack/';







        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $files=(object)$_FILES[ 'files' ];
        $allowed_exts=array('doc','docx','pdf');
        $col=[];    //  store the names of each file successfully uploaded - to be used in the sql update statement





        /* iterate through all uploaded files */
        foreach( $files->name as $i => $void ){
            try{
                $name = $files->name[$i];
                $size = $files->size[$i];
                $type = $files->type[$i];
                $tmp  = $files->tmp_name[$i];
                $error= $files->error[$i];

                if( $error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ){

                    /* is this filetype permitted? */
                    $ext = pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
                    if( is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) ){

                        if( in_array( $ext, $allowed_exts ) ){

                            /* store the uploaded file */
                            $target = $targetDir . $name;
                            $bytes = move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $target );

                            /* store the file name */
                            $col[]=$name;


                            $message=$bytes > 0 ? sprintf( 'The file "%s" has been uploaded.', $name ) : sprintf( 'There was a problem uploading "%s".', $name );
                            throw new Exception( $message );
                        } else {
                            throw new Exception( sprintf( 'Invalid filetype detected: %s', $ext ) );
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw new Exception( 'Warning: Possible file upload attack!' );
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new Exception( sprintf('Error: %d - %s', $error, uploaderror( $error ) ) );
                }
            }catch( Exception $e ){
                $output[]=$e->getMessage();
                continue;
            }
        }



        if( !empty( $col ) ){

            /* create the comma separated list of filenames to be used in the sql */
            $filenames = implode( ',', $col );

            /* create the prepared statement and make the bindings */
            $sql='update `users` set `file_name`=? where `username`=?';
            $stmt=$link->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $filenames, $username );

            /* execute the query */
            $result = $stmt->execute();
            $rows = $stmt->affected_rows;
            $stmt->close();

            /* log result & finish */
            $output[]=sprintf('Operation completed: %d rows updated, %d files uploaded, status: %s', $rows, count( $col ), $result );
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--

            action='/php/upload.php' 

        -->
        <form name='admin_upload' class='sign-in-htm' action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <div class='group'>
                <label for='user' class='label'>Enter Company or Employer Name:</label>
                <input id='username' name='username' type='text' class='input' required>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class='group'>
                <label for='attachment' class='label'>Upload Test Result PDF:</label>
                <input id='attachment' multiple name='files[]' accept='.doc,.docx,.pdf' type='file' class='input' />
            </div>
            <br>
            <button class='btn btn-primary btn-submit' name='submit' value='submit' input type='submit'>Submit Results</button>
            <?php

                if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $output ) ){
                    printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($output,true));
                }

            ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to look at this for me, i am currently using your code now, but its throwing 2 errors in dreamweaver at me on these 2 lines? - `$output=[]; //  log all actions & results to display to user if required` and `$col=[];    //  store the names of each file successfully uploaded - to be used in the sql update statement`

Comment: looks like Dreamweaver has not been updated. Try using `$output=array()` and `$col=array()`

Comment: Once again @RamRaider thanks very much indeed for taking the time to sort the problem, works like a dream. I will also use this as a basis for some code i need to write for displaying the Uploaded files back on to an HTML page in another part of the site.